# Geochart - mark one country with a special color

Tags: javascript, google-maps, charts

There is a standard example of Google Geochart, countries have a scale color depends on value. My question is how to mark one country, for example Canada, with an red one, but leave another countries like before. It is ok if Canada will be without value, just how to mark it in another color?
https://jsfiddle.net/8wowo9xc/

```
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

  function drawRegionsMap() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Country', 'Popularity'],
      ['Germany', 200],
      ['United States', 300],
      ['Brazil', 400],
      ['Canada', 500],
      ['France', 600],
      ['RU', 700]
    ]);

    var options = {};

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

The desire result:
[image: The desire result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify the `defaultColor` and give `Canada` no value, this will do exactly what you want.

So something like:

```
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

  function drawRegionsMap() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Country', 'Popularity'],
      ['Germany', 200],
      ['United States', 300],
      ['Brazil', 400],
      ['Canada', null],
      ['France', 600],
      ['RU', 700]
    ]);

      var options = {defaultColor: 'red'};

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try   :

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Country', 'Popularity'],
  ['Canada', 500]
]);
```

for other country or other color simply try this:

```
function drawRegionsMap() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Country', 'Popularity'],
      ['Ireland', 200],

  ]);

  var options = {
    //region: 'IT',
    //displayMode: 'markers',
    colorAxis: {colors: ['red']}
  };
```

Or for your last request try:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Country', 'Popularity'],
      ['Canada', 100],
      ['US', 1000], 
      ['Russia',500]

  ]);

  var options = {
    //region: 'IT',
    //displayMode: 'markers',
    colorAxis: {colors: ['red', 'green', 'lightgreen']}
  };



  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Final consideration: 
To use the polygons should already have polygons of various states with coordinates. and however it comes to writing a little program in JavaScript. If all you need is a data presentation with a state highlight (red) and the other with two colors (a darker green an a   lighter green) you better take advantage of the numerical value as I did in the example.  Create the list of states that interest you and state that you weaves mo put in evidence with the lowest value so that it is red, and intermediate value by displaying an intermediate color and so on.

The way forward is very dependent on your experience as a programmer.

Comment: But I need to keep data for another countries.

Comment: I've added a picture with desire result.

Comment: I have updateted the answer again, if you find this useful please rate it.

Comment: But if I have in my dataTable the next country: ['Brazil', 50], it will be also red, but should be light green. I need to have specific color only for specified country.

Comment: This way is not possibile if you want this behavior use google maps polygon and control them by program. In this sample  the color are related to in table and is related to the  value reporti in legend.

Comment: Thanks, to use google polygons I have to prepare a lot of coordinates for one country?

Comment: I have update the answer in the bottom look at consideration.